# unique delimiters while reading a file

Tags: java, file

I am reading a file into byte array, i have inserted some control command into it, which I need to decode in some other class. But how to identify and separate these information from rest of the content of file being read.  I need to use some unique character as a delimiter to identify the start and end of this control command in the byte array. Is there any unique character which i can use for this purpose ? That particular character should not be present in any normal binary file of any format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by definition there is no such a control character. But what you can do is store the array in a format that follows: [length of byte array] [byte array]. All you have to do then is read in an integer <- the length, create a new array of that length and read it fully.

---

EDIT:

Okay so use the following format:

The file name is null terminated so you know the delimiter there (this works because a file name is  ASCII only!). Then you have the length (an integer/long) and then the byte array.

All of the other methods mentioned above are unsafe and if you use a complex delimiter then: it's not perfect and takes up more space then using the a simple length variable...

Comment: I am following kinda same format, but i am not worried about the length of the byte array. Only thing is i need to save the file name in the first field instead of the byte array so that the byte array looks like this 

`[<filename>file_1_contents<filename2>file_2_contents.... <file_n_name>file_n_contents]`

Answer (score 2):

No, if it's a binary file, then in general, a byte can take on any value between 0 and 255.

One possible solution is to reserve one particular byte value as an "escape" character; let's say that you choose `'\'` for that purpose.  Then to represent a delimiter, you could insert the sequence `"\d"`, for instance.  Of course, to represent an *actual* `'\'`, you'll need to delimit that too; `"\\"`, for instance.

Comment: @Charlesworth The byte array will be something like this `[<filename>file_1_contents<filename2>file_2_contents.... <file_n_name>file_n_contents]` can i use `\`\\`` as a delimiter ? because even the file contents also can contain `\`\\``

Answer (score 1):

you can use come character sequence (or a byte sequence) and when you're decoding, if you find that sequence that it is delimiter.

Comment: but i will have to use some byte sequence which should not appear in the file contents. The file can be a file with any extension viz .exe .txt .dat etc